# Is it possible to export webform form snippets?

Tags: theming, webforms

I have built a small contact form with the Webform module. I want to paste it in the *node.tpl.php* and manually customize its code.

Can I export ready-to-work code from the user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. This is not the way Drupal theming and form building works. One of the main reasons would be that default Drupal hooks and theme functions will not work consistently if you can get a snapshot of a template, export it and change to your liking.

Let's take an example:

1. You create a webform with several fields.
2. Through this fictive module, you get the output which you can use in template files.
3. You use the code where you want.

The following will not work:

1. `hook_form_alter()` implementations. Fields added through dynamic conditions will not be there as well as custom CSS/JS.
2. Theming overrides will not work as well; say that your theme changes the way `textarea` elements are rendered. By exporting the form, you get the snapshot; if there is any dynamic condition, it won't work because the system cannot alter the markup anymore.

Solving the above problems would end up in a real mess, and I think this is just a tip of the iceberg.